# checking if for loop variable is at last index of string (not variable == string[index_Integer])

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, iteration

I feel like I am doing something wrong with the for loop and the user input

Whenever I do the for loop, I do believe that the local variable in the for loop has only one entry in the list

```
list[index_int] #returns value of the indexed entry in the list
user_input = "1234"
user_input[-1] >>> 4


    def print_numbers(n):
    for entry in n:
        if entry == "1":
            if (entry == n[-1]):
                print "E"
            else:
                print entry + "s,",
        elif entry == "0":
            if (entry == n[-1]):
                print "X"
            else:
                print entry + "X,",
        else:
            if (entry == n[-1]): #applies if entry is equal to the value of user input       at index value of (-1), which I do not want
                print entry + "L"
            else:
                print entry + "s,",            
user_input = raw_input()
if user_input.isdigit():
    print_numbers(user_input)
else:
    print user_input
```

When I wanted to put down 101 or 212, I get these

```
Intention -> 1s, X, E
Result:
E
X, E

Intention -> 2s, 1s, 2L
Result:
2L 
1s, 2L
```

I do believe that the cause is that during the for loop, each variable has only one element in its own list.

Is there not a way to check if the for loop is AT the list's (the string's) last index position (NOT having the variable equal to the value of the string's index i.e entry == n[-1])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate). And a bit more, but you should be able to figure that part out.

Comment: Thanks! and I have learned that I can make separate strings by using the list split :list[i:j]

and assigning new strings like this:
ones = n[len(n)-1:] and other_digits = n[:len(n)-1]
and I put each of them in their own for loops within their respective functions

thanks for the help though